# Oracle linux 6.6 is unable to boot

Tags: linux

This is W.R.T oracle linux 6.6 on HPE DL160 Gen9 server. Recently, I changed the motherboard of the server and the issue of server not booting up has persisted since then.

Error message " No UEFI bootable devices were detected, please attach a UEFI bootable device"

I tried changing the boot order, updating FW and reinstalling the bootloader as well. But the issue still persists. I request anyone who has come across similar issue and has the fix to help me out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you contact HP Support?

Comment: I contacted HPE support as well. They advised me to check the bootloader.  I did the same but the issue still persists. So I am trying other sources for help. Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a UEFI boot entry to the NVRAM on the motherboard (this is where boot entries are stored, rather than just probing an on-disk MBR like a BIOS does). These entries are pretty simple, and amounts to pointing to a disk by UUID, pointing to a partition on that disk that is formatted as FAT32 for the loader, and then pointing to the directory path on that partition for the loader itself (typically a file ending in .efi).

Oracle Linux uses efibootmgr to manage these entries, as does just about every other distribution. As a result, nearly any guide will be mostly correct.

The man page for efibootmgr is very helpful here: https://linux.die.net/man/8/efibootmgr

Rod Smith has a great guide on uEFI booting in general. It's a generic guide, but all of the advice is sound. In your case, particular attention should be paid to "Registering the boot loader with EFI": http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/installation.html

The majority of that guide will go over files and process that are already present and working on your system, but will help you track down the exact point of failure. You will have to do this work in a chroot if you can't get your system to boot, and that chroot must be on a live system that is booted as EFI, NOT via the BIOS or CSM.

Comment: Thank you.I shall try doing the same. If not, will come back for clarification.